# How to show custom page as Wordpress theme home page instead of index.php

Tags: wordpress

I would like to show a custom page when activate my theme with an Enter link instead of posts in the content area and also need to show same header, sidebar and footer as other pages. When click on the Enter our blog works same as other thems.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the page that you want to use as the index page in your wordpress admin panel. Then go to Readings Settings, and select Static Page, then select the new page you just created in the drop down menu to set it as the front page. Click Save Changes and the new index page will now be the first thing that visitors see when they go to your site. Does that solve your problem?